# Storing 2D arrays in 3D array

Tags: c, arrays, windows, pointers, memory

I'm currently trying to write a callback function for a database request.
The function is called for every result/database entry/row, and I want to store its 2D array (array of strings/char *) in an array.
My current solution looks like this:

Global declaration:

```
char ***entries;
```

Allocating memory for the first dimension in a setup function:

```
entries = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(char **)*200);
```

I'm working with the Windows API/Win32, basically it's malloc with zeroed memory and the last parameter referring to the size.

Initialising callback count and registering callback function for database execute:

```
cbCount = 0;
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, insertListEntries, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

Callback function:

```
static int insertListEntries(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    entries[cbCount] = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(argv)*argc); 
    memcpy(entries[cbCount], argv, sizeof(argv)*argc);
    ...
    cbCount++;
}
```

Parameters: argc is the size of argv/columns of the data, and argv the string array with the row data. 
I'm simply copying the memory data of argv into the 3D array.

However, the problem is now that for each callback all previous data sets are overwritten with the current result like this:

Callback 1: entries[0] = dataset1

Callback 2: entries[0] = dataset2, entries[1] = dataset2

...

Any ideas? I'm still trying to learn this concept of the "pointer/array-dualism" and memory allocation, but the best way for me is by doing it practically. Also, I DID study the theory beforehand alot, but I may have missed something.

**Edit**: added cbCount++;

Comment: Try checking strings in `argv`, do they actually get re-used? If they do, then you can't just copy `argv`, you need to copy each string.

Comment: Beware: you speak of 2D/3D arrays, but your code if for arrays of pointers which are different animals...

Comment: @hyde what do you mean with "get re-used"? I printed out the _entries_ array afterwards and all data was where it should be, also the _argv_ array always contained the current dataset for each callback.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sorry, yes you're right.

Comment: I mean, you have `argv` array of pointers to strings (char buffers). You stored the pointers to these buffers to `entries[0]`. If they get re-used and their contents changed, then it looks like `entries[0]` changed (the pointers didn't change, but the data at the char buffers they point to did).

Comment: Use something like `printf("entries[%d][0]=%p", cbCount, entries[cbCount][0])` after your `memcpy` to see the pointer values nicely.

Comment: @hyde Ah I get it! Since I just memcpy the 2D array with always the same pointers in the first dimension, the values in the 2nd dimension, accessed by the non-changing pointers, seem to never change! Thanks alot. I guess the best way to solve this is to copy plain values while recreating the structure manually again?

Comment: So you checked that this indeed is the problem? If so, I can write an actual answer for it.

Comment: Yes I think so, the first element of the 2nd dimension points always to the same adress.

Comment: @hyde I didn't mention you, I hope you were notified anyway!

Comment: No, only the poster of question/answer gets notified, unless you include the @ mention. Anyway, wrote an answer. Feel free to edit it if you want, or let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: @hyde Good to know. I'm pretty sure that's the correct answer, going to try this out tomorrow and come back if it's not, thank you very much!

Comment: Feel free to unaccept the answer and let me know if it's not right. A bit strange that https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html doesn't seem to indicate how the `argv` array should be used... Maybe it's explained elsewhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments to an answer:

It looks like sqlite re-uses buffers, and actually passes same pointers in the `argv` vector for different calls.

So when your `insertListEntries` is called first time (`cbCount` 0), parameter `argv` might contain pointer values `{ 0x1111100, 0x1111200, 0x1111300, ... }`, which you copy to your `entries[0]` array.

Then, when  `insertListEntries` is called second time (`cbCount` 1), the pointer values in `argv` are at least partially or sometimes the same! This means, the buffers allocated for result data are re-used, their contents changed. Because you copied the pointers to `entries[0]`, and now copy the possibly same pointers to `entries[1]`, they will point to same strings, which get overwritten for every call.

Solution is to copy the actual strings, the actual data, instead of just copying pointers to the library's internal buffers.